# Delphi XE10 comprimir una string en base 64 con ZLIb

Tags: delphi, base64

Pues resulta que tengo que enviar desde windows a dispositivos móviles, ios y android, y viceversa, por TCP una serie de datos, con Embarcadero Rad Studio 10 Berlin. Esos datos son strings en formato base 64.

Hasta aquí, ningun problema, envio y recibo. el problema es que necesito enviar a veces, una string grandisima, y por eso, estoy mirando algún método para comprimir el string.
He estado buscando y mirando algun metodo, y el mejor, parece ser que es usar la zlib para comprimir y descomprimir la string, y buscando he encontrado este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008014/delphi-xe-and-zlib-problems-ii) en el cual explica como hacerlo.El metodo funciona con string de texto de normal, pero al comprimir string en base64 ocupa mas.
Un ejemplo de una cadena muy pequeña que envío seria este:

> cEJNYkpCSThLVEh6QjNFWC9wSGhXQ3lHWUlBcGNURS83TFdDNVUwUURxRnJvZlRVUWd4WEFWcFJBNUZSSE9JRXlsaWgzcEJvTGo5anQwTlEyd1pBTEtVQVlPbXdkKzJ6N3J5ZUd4SmU2bDNBWjFEd3lVZmZTR1FwNXRqWTVFOFd2SHRwakhDOU9JUEZRM00wMWhnU0p3MWxxNFRVdmdEU2pwekhwV2thS0JFNG9WYXRDUHhTdnp4blU5Vis2ZzJQYnRIdllubzhKSFhZeUlpckNtTGtUZHVHOTFncHVUWC9FSTdOK3JEUDBOVzlaTngrcEdxcXhpRWJ1ZXNUMmdxOXpJa0ZEak1ORHBFenFVSTlCdytHTy==

El problema es que con la longitud de las cadenas reales que envío, mas de 26000 caracteres, al hacer estas pruebas, ocupan más. No se si podrá comprimir de alguna manera estas strings, la verdad es que en estas cosas estoy muy pez.

Las funciones que uso son estas:

```
uses
  SysUtils, Classes, ZLib, EncdDecd;

function CompressAndEncodeString(const Str: string): string;
var
  Utf8Stream: TStringStream;
  Compressed: TMemoryStream;
  Base64Stream: TStringStream;
begin
  Utf8Stream := TStringStream.Create(Str, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    Compressed := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      ZCompressStream(Utf8Stream, Compressed);
      Compressed.Position := 0;
      Base64Stream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.ASCII);
      try
        EncodeStream(Compressed, Base64Stream);
        Result := Base64Stream.DataString;
      finally
        Base64Stream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Compressed.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Utf8Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

function DecodeAndDecompressString(const Str: string): string;
var
  Utf8Stream: TStringStream;
  Compressed: TMemoryStream;
  Base64Stream: TStringStream;
begin
  Base64Stream := TStringStream.Create(Str, TEncoding.ASCII);
  try
    Compressed := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      DecodeStream(Base64Stream, Compressed);
      Compressed.Position := 0;
      Utf8Stream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
      try
        ZDecompressStream(Compressed, Utf8Stream);
        Result := Utf8Stream.DataString;
      finally
        Utf8Stream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Compressed.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Base64Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Gracias de antemano y perdon por la chapa.

Comment: Una cadena codificada en base64 siempre ocupará más "memoria" o "espacio" que una cadena sin codificar (cuya base es el octeto, es decir, 256). Ahora, ¿de donde viene el requerimiento de utilizar base64? Si tu debes enviar cadenas de un punto a otro en aplicaciones bajo tu control por TCP, te suguiero olvidarte de base 64 y enviar directamente las cadenas. Ya sobre estas, puedes aplicar algún tipo de compresión y obviamente ganarás mucho más.

Comment: Aclaremos esas dudas y con gusto te respondo con un ejemplo que te pueda servir de base.